# CCMenuItemFont adds stroke

Tags: cocos2d-x

CCLabelTTF has property enableStroke.

Just wonder if CCMenuItemFont can support stroke enable?

or is there any method to create similar result

your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MenuItemFont creates a menu item with given string and uses label just to display the text, nothing more. You need MenuItemLabel to create a menu item with custom label like this:

```
auto textLabel = LabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Arial", 22);
// XXX: Additional settings here

auto menuItem = MenuItemLabel::create(textLabel, CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::onMenuItemClicked, this));
menuItem->setPosition(Point(200, 100));

auto menu = Menu::create(menuItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
addChild(menu);
```